# Is it possible to disable elements in a listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tk-toolkit

I have this code snippet:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    list = ['one','disable me','two']
    listbox = tk.Listbox(self,height=len(list))
    for item in list:
      listbox.insert(tk.END, item)
    listbox.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = SampleApp()
  app.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to disable the 2nd selection line, so it can not be selected? Additionally, is it possible to show it in a different (grayish) font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no method to accomplish this goal. But there are other ways! With `itemconfig(index, fg="gray")` you can set the font colour to gray. Also you can bind your listbox to the `<<ListBoxSelection>>` event and define a callback method. In this method just check the index of the selected item with `.curselection()` and then you can clear the selection if it matches the index of the item.

Code snippet:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        list = ['one','disable me','two']

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self,height=len(list))
        for item in list:
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, item)
        self.listbox.pack()
        self.disable_item(1)

    def disable_item(self,index):
        self.listbox.itemconfig(index, fg="gray")
        self.listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",
                          lambda event, index=index: self.no_selection(event, index))

    def no_selection(self, event, index):
        if self.listbox.curselection()[0] in str(index):
            self.listbox.selection_clear(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Alternativly you can create your own Widget, which just contain and place Label-widgets so you have full control of those widgets. Then you can set the state of the Label as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Fantastic solution and so elegant. Just a note which is self.listbox.curselection()[0] also needs to be defined as str(self.listbox.curselection()[0]) otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: also, was wondering if this can be configured to work for multiple items? I noticed after i disable two items using this method, the first one becomes selectable (although still grey)

Comment: You are right, but the solution was for Python 2.7, which has a slitly different behaviour. And it's better to check the index in the curselections, like so: `if index in self.listbox.curselection():` . For multiple unselection i would just use a List of indices